# Approximating $a^n -b^n$

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

Perhaps this is silly, but nonetheless here it is. Let $a>b>0$. We know exactly what the difference is for $a^n-b^n$ by the standard formula. I am interesting in approximating it though with a much simpler formula, even if we lose accuracy. It was inspired by a friend asking me if I have any idea how much $11^{100} - 7^{100}$ more or less is without using some engine.

My thoughts are that a naïve approximation is just $a^n$ since for large values of $a$ compared to $b$ and large $n$ it is "good enough". If we want to take some kind of average over what $b$ could be, we could define $f(x) = a^n-x^n$ and take its average value on $[0,a]$ by integrating and obtaining $Avg(f) = \frac{n}{n+1}a^n$. Neither of these ideas are very good and most specifically they don't take into account the knowledge of what $b$ is. Can we do better? All ideas are welcome, independently if they offer a simpler approximation with more error, or a more elegant one with closer true value. I am just curious about it.

Comment: $\left(\frac{7}{11}\right)^{100}<3\,10^{-20}$. The true challenge is to compute $11^{100}$.

Comment: Good point, I was computing the error relative to $a^n$.  So much for speaking off the cuff.

Comment: It's kinda funny, I just deleted my comment because re-thinking it I got confused that I was wrong and realized how you computed it. And now re-re-thinking it-I realize I was indeed correct the first time and can't undelete the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about
$$ a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\cdots +b^{n-1})\le (a-b)\cdot na^{n-1},$$
which beats $\le a^n$ when $b\ge \frac n{n+1}a$? (And below that mark, $a^n$ is in fact *quite* good)

Comment: Side note: the mean value theorem tells us that in fact we have $a^n - b^n = (a-b) \cdot n c^{n-1}$ for some $c$ between $a$ and $b$. Not that this is necessarily useful since it doesn't tell us what $c$ is. But it does give us a lower bound for $a^n - b^n$, namely $(a-b) \cdot nb^{n-1}$ (which of course your method also gives).